# class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne while upgrading hibernate/JPA/Spring boot version to 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I was trying to upgrade spring-boot version to 3.1.1 and seeing this issue

Comment: A `ClassCastException` is a runtime-exception that occurs during runtime in your code. Please share the relevant code as [example].

Answer (score 3):

Encountered too during upgrade from SpringBoot 2.7 to 3.1
The problem turned out to be that there was a one-to-many relationship declaration (ToOne)

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fieldInChildEntity")
    var children: MutableSet<ChildEntity> = mutableSetOf()
```

and the column was not of type of the corresponding ParentEntity, but rather a String (a BasicValue)

```
    @Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME")
    val fieldInChildEntity: String?,
```

It should have been:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_PK")
    var parent: ParentEntity?,
```